# How to use offline MbTiles with Telerik's WPF map control?

Tags: c#, mbtiles, wpf

Telerik's UI for WPF includes a map control: [UI for WPF - RadMap](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/map.aspx).

There's some discussion of how to configure it to use a local mapping service: 
[Implement custom map provider](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radmap/how-to/howto-custom-provider.html), but it seems to be oriented towards directories of tiles: [Offline Map Server](http://www.telerik.com/forums/offline-map-server).

Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work with an MbTiles file?

Comment: It looks like its expecting to work via a URI. So possibly you can register a URI handler (maybe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx or maybe Telerik has some extra approach) for your mbtiles: uris? Have you asked Telerik support?